# how to get remain of `delete_at` without destruction

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to delete a value from an `Array` and get remain of it like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.delete_at(2)
=> 3
a
=> [1, 2, 4]
```

How can I get `[1, 2, 4]` without destruction of the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do, admittedly, they don't seem very elegant:

```
a[0..1] + a[3..-1]
# => [1, 2, 4]

a.dup.tap { |x| x.delete_at(2) }
# => [1, 2, 4]

a.values_at(0..1, 3..-1)
# => [1, 2, 4]
```

Personally, I think the way which conveys your intention best is:

```
a.reject.with_index { |_, i| i == 2 }
# => [1, 2, 4]
```